# Angular Bootstrap modal not updating table

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Angular Bootstrap modal not updating table, if `$scope.test()` call from ng-click event, it refresh table but from `$scope.closeAdjustmentModal`(function for closing modal) it is not getting updated.

```
$scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation : false,
                    scope : $scope,
                    size : 'lg',
                    controller : 'myCtrl',
                    templateUrl : '/showAdjustmentUI'

                   });

$scope.test= function() {
    $http.get('/myurl/getById/' + $scope.id).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.patData = data;
    });
}

$scope.closeAdjustmentModal = function() {
    $scope.test();
    $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, you are trying to call your maincontroller method `test` from your modalcontroller.

For this kind of scenario you can use `closed.then` callback to call the `test` function.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation : false,
                scope : $scope,
                size : 'lg',
                controller : 'myCtrl',
                templateUrl : '/showAdjustmentUI'
}).closed.then(function(){
  $scope.test();
});
```

Comment: So can't you use this `closed.then` callback to call your `test` method??

Comment: Both are in same controller 'myCtrl'. Actually, test() is also get called, when $scope.closeAdjustmentModal() is called, if I put alert after success it popup but it is not able to bind $scope.patData to UI

Comment: Then this is a problem with your data binding. Edit your answer with the html code as well

Comment: But if directly called test() from ng-click, data get shown on UI. So, I don't think it is databinding problem at UI. It is not binding data if it called from modal.

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting different kind of data values when you close the modal?

Comment: Let me clear, when test() is called from ng- click at UI having datatable its working but when 
$scope.closeAdjustmentModal is called from modal test() is also get called but in this case, datatable won't get updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137231/discussion-between-user3107804-and-dilumn).